# Adding a prototype to an Imported/Required class and properly showing Intellisense

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, prototype, intellisense

In VSCode, when adding a prototype to an imported class, hovering over `bar()` just displays `any`.

[image: any]

```
const { Class } = require('module.js');

Class.prototype.bar = function() {};

var foo = new Class();

foo.bar();
```

On the other hand, here it displays `(method) Class.bar(): void`

[image: (method) Class.bar(): void @name — bar]

```js
class Class {};

/**
 * @name bar
 */
Class.prototype.bar = function() {};

var foo = new Class();

foo.bar();
```

How can I make it so when you add a prototype to an imported class shows the correct Intellisense tooltip?

Comment: "*adding a prototype to an imported class*" - don't do that. What other modules might be adding more methods there? Overwrite your `bar` method even? You can't know, and neither does Intellisense. It's just non-idiomatic code that it doesn't expect to handle. What is your reason for not placing the `bar` method in the same module as the class?

Comment: in the image capture why don't you show the context to the left of the image, there are more then one `.bar`, and this is not my goto bar.

Comment: @rioV8 There's only 1 `.bar();` in each code snippet, it shouldn't be too difficult to figure out

Comment: @Bergi I'm adding a method to a class from an npm module (in my case, TextChannel from discord.js)

Comment: @Theblockbuster1 Well, yeah, don't do that. Either wrap the class or inherit from it. Don't mess with stuff you don't own.